# Cannot query archive when the room is flooding with messages

Tags: ejabberd

When user keep on sending messages in the room.. other members cannot query the archive from the room until most of the messages been distributed to all members.

Please help to advice how to solve this problem, is it .
I'm running `ejabberd 21.01.7` Community Edition.

The process of query archive should not be blocking while user sending many many messages in the room.

Thanks